# MongoDB.Driver throwing exception with method failed : MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.SemaphoreSlimSignalable.IsSignaled

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDB.Driver throwing exception with method failed : MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.SemaphoreSlimSignalable.IsSignaled when doing the performance test on Azure Function with servicebustrigger

I'm doing the performance test on the Azure function with ServiceBusTrigger with topics and subscriptions. I have mongo db as a database behind.

In my scenario, I have ScheduledEnqueueTime configured for service bus message to be sent on topics. When I load the the system with 500 concurrent calls on same time (ex: 2023-06-07 12:32:00). I have started getting exception as **System.OperationCanceledException** with method failed : MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.SemaphoreSlimSignalable.IsSignaled (screenshot attached). I have concurrentcalls set to 200 for azure service bus at function app and instances are set to 10 manually.
Image : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkp1U.png)

I'm not able to understand why it throwing exception. Is it a deadlock at MongoDB side?
Please help me here.

Comment: report this to mongodb .net driver team

Comment: Theres not enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: this happens due to a concurrency issue - the way I solved it was by sending CancellationToken.None to the queries from the background job - I do hope the mongodb .net driver team can solve this...